# UIImage refresh swift3

Tags: swift, uiimage

I have some default images in the viewController and after a user action, it loads an external image and replace the default one.

The problem, it loads the image but doesnt refresh unless i change the viewController to other one

```
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
           self.getDataFromUrl(thumbURL, completion: { (data) in
                        let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                        self.cityImageView.image = image
                        print("img refreshed")
              })
           }

 func getDataFromUrl(_ url:String, completion: @escaping ((_ data: Data?) -> Void)) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            if let newData = data {
                completion(newData)
            }
        }) .resume()
    }
```

So i get a print out `img refreshed` but in front-end nothing changes, what am i missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you set image on the main thread?

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.getDataFromUrl(thumbURL, completion: { (data) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let image = UIImage(data: data!)
            self.cityImageView.image = image
            print("img refreshed")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: thanks it works but still don't get it why double main thread?

Comment: it's right ,but you can delete first GCD main . I think the method is run in sub thread. so you just call main thread in closure.

Comment: I just copied your code and put the completion block in main thread since it involves UIKit. I don't know why you need the first dispatch. As @stark has commented, you probably don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to put it into GCD queue.

Completion block will be executed in the delegate queue (in this case, main queue). Just notice you should define capture list to avoid memory leak.

```
self.getDataFromUrl(imageURL, completion: { [unowned self] (data) in
                let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                self.imageView.image = image
                print("img refreshed")
            })

func getDataFromUrl(_ url:String, completion: @escaping ((_ data: Data?) -> Void)) {

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            if let newData = data {
                completion(newData)
            }
        }) .resume()
    }
```

Let me know if it fixed your issue.